# Flash message not rendered when redirected through auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm successfully using flash messaging throughout my web application and do so using the [Laracasts Flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) package.

On my application users have the ability to change their email addresses, for which they are sent a link to confirm this.

When they click the link and are already logged in then this works fine and they are redirected to their profile successfully with a flash message to confirm this.

However when I click on the link, but am not logged in to the account, the change goes through successfully and then I am redirected to the login page as you cannot access the profile page without being logged in. This is intended, however my flash message isn't shown and doesn't appear to be included in the session data.

The function that handles the changing of the email address is included in my `except` array for the `auth` middleware on this controller but the profile page isn't.

As far as I can tell this should work... Any ideas?

```
public function emailconfirm($token)
    {

        $result = EmailChange::where('token', '=', $token)->get();

        if (!$result->isEmpty())
        {
            if ($result[0]->confirmed == 1)
            {
                flash()->error('You have already confirmed your email address using that token.');
                return redirect('/user');
            }

            if(count(User::where('email', $result[0]->new_email)->first()) > 0)
            {
                flash()->error('That email address has since been used to register an account, so it cannot be verified. Please contact us via the forums if you need help.');
                return redirect('/');
            }

            $user = User::find($result[0]->memberid);
            $user->email = $result[0]->new_email;
            $user->save();

            $result[0]->confirmed = 1;
            $result[0]->save();

            flash()->success('Email successfully updated.');

            return redirect('/user');
        }
    }
```

My login page does have the necessary code to show the flash message.

Comment: Did your routes grouped in the `web` middelware ?

Comment: @Maraboc I'm using Laravel 5.1, there is no web middleware

Comment: Well, AFAIK, flash means 1. Put data to session storage. 2. Navigate to another page. 3. Possibly display previously stored data. 4. Destroy flash message. What happens in your case is that because of redirect it destroys flash message before you get to the login page.